# How do I use "defaults write" correctly from pkgbuild / productbuild?

Tags: xcode, macos, permissions, productbuild, pkgbuild

I'm building an installer package with

```
pkgbuild --component MyApp.app ... --scripts scriptsdir MyApp.pkg
```

And I would like to set some user defaults after installation. So I made a `postinstall` script with:

```
defaults write com.mycompany.MyApp key -string value
```

However, this doesn't work — the settings get written to `/var/root/Library/Preferences`, and are only accessible by `sudo defaults read`.

So instead I tried this:

```
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.mycompany.MyApp key -string value
```

Now they get written to the right place, but the permissions are wrong — `stat` shows the permissions on the plist file are `-rw------- 1 root wheel`, and `defaults read` can't access them. How can I get this to work correctly?

Answer (score 4):

Don't do this.

If your app requires certain "default" defaults to operate, on first launch, notice they aren't there and write them out.

You are assuming too much about the installation: that the user doing the install is the primary user of the software; that only one user on the machine might be interested in using the software; that anyone is logged in at all!

Instead have your app set up its default environment on first launch. This will work for all users on the machine, including users created *after* your software is installed.

Comment: Yes, I definitely appreciate the value of `-[NSUserDefaults registerDefaults:]`. But my motivation in this particular case is a desire to separate company-internal configuration from the actual "'default' defaults" — the goal is to do so without modifying the source code, so that it can be released cleanly as open-source software. In this case, the installation assumptions you mentioned are actually valid.

Comment: So if you are convinced that writing out defaults in a postflight script is the right thing to do, consider `sudo -u $USER defaults write ...` `man sudo` to get the basic concept. Alternately, change the owner after writing. But be aware that your script _will_ break if your assumptions are wrong, and your package may not be installable by automated systems (since $USER won't necessarily be set to a useful value).